# Applying a median filter to a dicom image in python

Tags: python, filter, scipy, dicom, scikit-image

Apply 5x5, 10x10, and 35x35 median filters to a dicom image

```
dicom.read_file("ACR CT Phantom_1.dcm") <-- this is the image
```

I know you can't see the image but maybe you can help with the syntax of filtering it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

1. Do whatever you need to to get the image into a numpy array
2. `skimage.filters.median(image, selem=np.ones((5, 5)))`